# C#/WPF-Abnormal High RAM usage when scrolling RichTextBox Up and Down

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a RichTextBox in my project.

This is it's definition in XAML:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbxConsole" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    <FlowDocument PagePadding="0" >
        <Paragraph >
            The program is ready.
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

This is how I append text to it:

```
public static void AppendText(this RichTextBox box, string text, string color)
{
    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();

    Paragraph par = new Paragraph();

    Run run2 = new Run(text);
    run2.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFromString(color);
    par.Inlines.Add(run2);

    try
    {
        box.Document.Blocks.Add(par);
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryException OME)
    {
        box.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    }
}
```

This is how I call the AppendText function:

```
private void ScanTask_TaskTerminated(object sender, TaskTerminatedArgs e)
{
    ...
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        rtbxConsole.AppendText(DateTime.Now + ": " + e.eCurrentTask.MainScale + "Task terminated manually." + e.eCurrentTask.TestNumTotal + " tests were excuted." , "ForestGreen");
        rtbxConsole.ScrollToEnd();
    });
}
```

I added about 4616 lines(394Kb in total)to it using the 'AppendText' function above.  However,when i scroll the vertical scroll bar up and down, the RAM usage goes up rapidly. But when i stop doing it , the RAM usage stops going up. If I do this  continuously,the RAM usage will rise about 300MB more and then falls to the starting value.How does this happen? I mean, it's only 394kb text! How can it use that a large RAM?

I'm using VS2015 pro with .NET 4.6. This project is a WPF application project,and I'm using both Telerik and Mahapp in it. I compile it using 'Debug' mode and 'Any CPU' option,and I check the RAM usage using the Task Manager,which is part of my Win10 system.

ps:I try to create a project that only include a richtextbox to it, append all the text by copy-paste and scroll up and down.This issue does not exist in that case.

Any information is appreciated.

Comment: In which sense is this "abnormal"? What is your expectation? Do you have any question at all?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. I mean, it's only 394kb text in a richtextbox! How can it use a 300Mb large RAM?Is there anyway not letting the RAM usage grow so high?

Comment: You haven't even told us how often you call AppendText. Once per line, or once in total with all the text?

Comment: @WoodyJohnson fix your question imo. If it is 100% reproducable from its contents, someone will be bored enough from work to use a profiler i'd imagine

Comment: you write "ps:I try to create a project that only include a richtextbox to it, append all the text by copy-paste and scroll up and down.This issue does not exist in that case." <-- So what do you learn from this ? is the problem sourced to that richtextbox or perhaps somewhere else?

Comment: @Clemens:The appending period is already done when i scroll the richtextbox up and down.When doing the append, it's once per line.

Comment: So you're creating 4616 Paragraph and 4616 Run (and probably 4616 SolidColorBrush) instances.

Comment: @Clemens OMG dude i guess that may be the reason! I'll try to append all the text in one paragraph and see what happens.Thank you!

Comment: You may start your optimization by replacing the`string color` parameter of the AppendText method by `Brush foreground` and pass `Brushes.ForestGreen` instead of a string. Then perhaps use a LineBreak instead of a Paragraph.

Comment: @G.Y I'm writing this just because it may save your time()...I still have no idea why this happens, but i  think Clemens' right..There are tooo many paragraphs.